# Drupal 8 Views Slideshow Images sized incorrectly in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drupal

Live slideshow https://www.baywaycopperalloys.com

The following styling sizes [Drupal 8 Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) slides correctly in all browsers except IE 11.  `.img-responsive` is the selector applied.

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The width can be corrected using `max-width:100vw` but then the container height set by the javascript inline on the elements is incorrect.

How do I get correct 100% widths and auto heights in IE 11 using Views Slideshow?

```
<div id="views_slideshow_cycle_div_home_slider-block_1_1" class="views_slideshow_cycle_slide views_slideshow_slide views-row-2 views_slideshow_cycle_hidden views-row-even" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 5; opacity: 1; width: 1903px; height: 464px;">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-even">
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-slide-image">
      <div class="field-content">
        <img src="/sites/bayway/files/2017-02/banner-2.jpg" width="2200" height="536" alt="Bayway Copper Alloys" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="views-field views-field-field-display-order">
      <div class="field-content">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to use that slider?

Comment: It has to be natively supported in Drupal...

Comment: It's not responsive at all for me on OSx Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the update from the Flexslider team to 8.x-2.0-alpha2 this issue is resolved in all browsers.  We replaced the 8.x-2.x-dev module files and add the Flexslider library files and done!

Answer (score 0):

First remove .form group which contain the whole slider from views (you can use rewrite output or in your template) so controls will be centred

then try this , and tell me if slider controls works

```
.views_slideshow_main{
    height:310px
}
.view-home-slider .img-responsive {
    height:300px;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
.views-slideshow-controls-bottom{
    z-index: 9999999999999;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Height is being calculated by Drupal Views Slideshow based on browser width (or in the IE 11 case monitor width) so setting one height for all widths will not work.  It is a responsive site with a responsive slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply image style to the images in slideshow. Right now height of images in 556px. This is what is rendering in IE as its takes height auto. If image style is applied, then it will be consistent in all browser.

Also you need to align the slideshow container in center. Right now it is aligned left. With this issue will be resolved for all browsers.
[image: Image aligned left]

Comment: Height is being calculated by Drupal Views Slideshow based on browser width (or in the IE 11 case monitor width) so setting one height for all widths will not work.  It is a responsive site with a responsive slideshow.